# Obtaining the integral kernel of an operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let's say I have a (bounded for now) linear operator $A$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ say, and I would like to find its kernel (which I'll suppose exists), i.e. a function $K(x, y)$ such that $Af(x) = \int K(x, y)f(y)dy$.

Is it possible to find an expression for $K(x, y)$ if I know how $A$ acts on every function? For instance, I know $\langle Af, g \rangle$ and some of my initial thoughts is that if I can let $f = \delta_y$ and $g = \delta_x$ then $A\delta_y(z) = \int K(z, u)\delta_y(u)du = K(z, y)$ and therefore $$\langle Af, g \rangle = \int A\delta_y(z)\overline{\delta_x(z)}dz = \int K(z, y) \delta_x(z)dz = K(x, y).$$

But I'm not sure if this method is permitted. I can't think of any counterexamples but I know the delta does not belong to $L^2$ and can't be approximated by $L^2$ functions. What's the usual technique to get the kernel of an integral operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one-to-one correspondence between $L^2$ integral kernels and Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $L^2$. If $A$ is HS on $L^2$, and $(e_j)$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2$, then the kernel can be expressed as $$K(x,y)=\sum\limits_{j,k}\langle Ae_j,e_k\rangle \overline{e_j}e_k.$$

Here is one especially convenient scenario: If the operator is pseudodifferential, and you know the symbol $a$, then you can alternatively express the kernel in terms of an oscillatory integral involving the symbol (which is, of course, equivalent to the above):

$$K(x,y)=(2\pi)^{-n}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} a(x,\xi) e^{i(x-y)\cdot\xi}\, d\xi. $$ I'd say that I personally look at it in the latter sense more frequently, though this likely depends on the work that you do.

Comment: I'm interested in the question more generally so the operator doesn't have to be pseudodifferential. On the topic of the first formula - as I understand it the usual choice of $(e_j)$ is probably the eigenfunctions of $A$ since $\langle Ae_j, e_k \rangle$ is nice and easy to work with, but are there any examples of applications of the first formula where the $(e_j)$ are not eigenfunctions of $A$? I suppose I could use another operator's eigenbasis (e.g. maybe $(x^ne^{-x^2/2})_{n \geq 0}$) - is that the rough idea?

Comment: @pencilwriter it works for any orthonormal basis of $L^2$, actually. An eigenbasis would be convenient but is not necessary. This is related to HS operators having a definition which is independent of basis. Of course, HS operators are also a somewhat restrictive class.

Comment: With that being said, not every bounded $L^2$ operator will have an $L^2$ kernel, else they'd be HS. So, HS operators are a pretty important case to consider.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I thought of an eigenbasis of an operator w/ discrete spectrum since these are the only bases that I know of for $L^2$. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer to field any more suggestions - I think the first method is most appropriate (since I can't guarantee the operator is PD), but at the same time it's surprising that there's not an easy way to recover the kernel when we have full knowledge of the operator (or the bilinear form $\langle Af, g \rangle$) and it's surprising that we need a nice $(e_j)$ for which the $\langle Ae_j, e_k \rangle$ is nice to compute.